# How to extract string between the first occurrence of : and a colon

Tags: linux, text-processing, sed, files, search

I have a long file that I need to reprocess for entering it into database. The file's data are in this format:

```
Error for: 111.222.55.1,[ZXX: Error message] some text (_xxx.c:833)
Error for: 198.243.55.25,[ZXX: Error message] some text (_xxx.c:833)
Unexpected error for: 198.245.175.52,[Errno 104] some text here
```

I need to re arrange the file to be like this:

```
Error for,111.222.55.1,[ZXX: Error message] some text (_xxx.c:833)
Error for,198.243.55.25,[ZXX: Error message] some text (_xxx.c:833)
Unexpected error for,198.245.175.52,[Errno 104] some text here
```

1) Please note that there is a space after the word `for:`
2) That the character `:` can occur more than once in a line as you see in the example. So I need to replace the first occurrence after the `for:[space]`

I thought of `sed` to search and replace. But do not know how to limit the search for the position I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using SED:

```
sed -e 's/: /,/' file > newFile

Error for,111.222.55.1,[ZXX: Error message] some text (_xxx.c:833)
Error for,198.243.55.25,[ZXX: Error message] some text (_xxx.c:833)
Unexpected error for,198.245.175.52,[Errno 104] some text here
```

- By default, `sed` replaces the 1st occurrence.

Comment: I want to output in a new file. Not change the same file.

Comment: How does it know that thee `:` is the first occurrence? I do not want to change every `:`. Can you clarify your command briefly please?

Comment: @user9371654 , Check my update.

Answer (score 1):

`awk` solution:

```
 awk '{sub(/: /,",")}1' file


Error for,111.222.55.1,[ZXX: Error message] some text (_xxx.c:833)
Error for,198.243.55.25,[ZXX: Error message] some text (_xxx.c:833)
Unexpected error for,198.245.175.52,[Errno 104] some text here
```

Comment: I do not want spaces before and after comma.

Comment: Please check the output I posted. This is not what I need.